# How to find the maximum value's variable name?

Tags: c++, variables, c++11, max

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int c = 3;
int d = 4;
```

How would I find out if the maximum integer value is stored in variable `d`?

Comment: Sounds like you want an array (`std::array`). Containers come with handy algorithms like `std::max_element`.

Comment: `std::max({a,b,c,d})` would also work, but do what chris says unless you have a good reason not to use an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an `array` instead of these variables, then you will easily find max element. See the example [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/max_element/)

Comment: It is an incorrect answer because the question is about separate variables.

Comment: Well, I just though of suggesting a better approach to use a number of values

Answer (score 2):

Use an array (instead of individual variables) and report the array index as the "answer"

Answer (score 2):

You can do it the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    int c = 3;
    int d = 4;

    if ( std::max( { a, b, c, d } ) == d ) 
    {
        std::cout << "d contains the maximum equal to " << d << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
d contains the maximum equal to 4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a variadic template:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, typename U, typename ... Args>
T& max_ref(T&, U&, Args& ... );

template <typename T, typename U>
T& max_ref(T& t, U& u) {
    return t < u ? u : t;
}
template <typename T, typename U, typename ... Args>
T& max_ref(T& t, U& u, Args& ... args) {
    return max_ref(t < u ? u : t, args ...);
}

int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    int c = 3;
    int d = 4;
    max_ref(a, b, c, d) = 42;
    std::cout << d << '\n';
}
```

Note: You will not get the variable holding the maximum, only a reference to a variable (which is anonymous).

Answer (score 0):

if limited to 4 variables only, and you don't want to go with the array route (which is recommended if we have a lot of variables). You could use the code below based on if-else statements:

```
int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    int max;
    if (a > b) {
        max = a;
    }
    else {
        max = b;
    }
    if (c > max) {
        max = c;
    }
    if (d > max) {
        max = d;
    }
    return max;
}
```